# How do I replace a string in python with a None Value?

Tags: python, list, replace, split

```
var = "this is a string"
var = var.replace('a' , '')
var = var.split(' ')
print(var)
```

The above code displays:

```
['this','is','','string']
```

I want it to display:

```
['this','is','string']
```

How do I do that?

What have I tried:
Assigning none to the Argument 2, but It raises an error 'TypeError: replace() argument 2 must be str, not None'

Comment: Don't give an argument to `split`. `var.split()` will split on any kind and length of whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

You might not want to replace `"a"` within words, so you better filter after the split:

```
var = "this is a string"

var = [w for w in var.split() if w != "a"]
```